# Where is the thread going when a future leaves scope?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

With threads I know that `terminate()` is called when the thread-variable leaves scope:

```
size_t fibrec(size_t n) {
  return n<2 ? 1 : fibrec(n-2)+fibrec(n-1);
}

int main() {
    std::thread th{ fibrec, 35 };
    // no join here
} // ~th will call terminate().
```

`th`s destructor will call `terminate()` when it leaves scope.

But what about `future`s? Where is the thread they run going? Is it detached? How is it ended?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future> // async
using namespace std;

size_t fibrec(size_t n) {
    return n<2 ? 1 : fibrec(n-2)+fibrec(n-1);
}

struct Fibrec {
    size_t operator()(size_t n) { return fibrec(n); }
    const size_t name_;
    Fibrec(size_t name) : name_(name) {}
    ~Fibrec() { cerr << "~"<<name_<< endl; }
};

void execit() {
    auto f1 = async( Fibrec{33}, 33 );
    auto f2 = async( Fibrec{34}, 34 );
    // no fx.get() here !!!
}; // ~f1, ~f2, but no terminate()! Where do the threads go?

int main() {
    auto f0 = async( Fibrec{35}, 35 );
    execit();
    cerr << "fib(35)= " << f0.get() << endl;
}
```

When `execit()` is left the futures `f1` and `f2` are destroyed. But their threads should still be running? The destructor of `Fibrec` is called, of course. **But where are the threads going?** The program does not crash, so I guess, the become joined? Or maybe detached? Or are they stopped or canceled? I believe that is not trivially done in C++11?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `future` is the result of the async operation, it's is not a thread by itself.  The `async` function spawns a new thread to do the computation, and when that is finished, the result is written to a `future` object.

Depending on the implemented policy, you will either have to call `.get()`  or `.wait()` on the future to get the result.  Invoking this will do the work on the **thread on which it is called**

> If policy is `std::launch::async` then runs INVOKE(fff,xyz...) on its
>   own thread. **The returned std::future will become ready when this
>   thread is complete**, and will hold either the return value or exception
>   thrown by the function invocation. *The destructor of the last future
>   object associated with the asynchronous state of the returned
>   std::future shall block until the future is ready.*
>
> If policy is `std::launch::deferred` then fff and xyz... are stored
>   in the returned std::future as a deferred function call. The first
>   call to the wait() or get() member functions on a future that shares
>   the same associated state will execute INVOKE(fff,xyz...)
>   synchronously on the thread that called wait() or get().

Comment: That's the quote I needed: *The destructor of the last future object associated with the asynchronous state of the returned std::future shall block until the future is ready.*

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very basic `std::async` implementation(without a task-pool or `std::launch` stuff):

```
template< class Function, class... Args>
std::future<typename std::result_of<Function(Args...)>::type> 
       async( Function&& f, Args&&... args ) 
{
    std::packged_task<F(Args...)> task(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto ret = task.get_future();
    std::thread t(std::move(task));
    t.detach();
    return ret;   
}
```

You see that the actually computation is done in a detached thread. The future is just a synchronization object. `std::packaged_task` is just another wrapper for the `std::promise` `set_value`/`set_exception` logic.

Comment: Is it standard compliant? You create a thread, `detach` it so it continues to run, then you return the future -- but leave the scope of the thread object. I guess it doesn't matter that the `thread`object is destroyed? The `future` carries all information? But you `move`ed the `task` into the `thread`'s constructor... hrmm... Well, I think I can see how this ''may'' work, but I meant "by the standard text", not by an example implementation. Very intersting though, anyway. I will keep this under my pillow, too.

Comment: @towi Yes, it is. We may leave the scope before the thread finishes because we detached it. If `std::thread::joinable` returns true and the thread destructor is called `std::terminate` is called. However when you detach a thread it is no longer joinable and as such it is safe to leave the scope. The future stores all the information which is needed on the caller side. The information which is needed on the producer side(the `std::promise`) is being moved to the thread which executes the function. The future serves as a communication channel between those two sides.